# adding 220v 50 amp circuit-breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

can i add double breaker into an empty slot circle "1"? this will be for 220v hot tub.

i have not tried anything yet, looking at circle "1" i have a feeling that breaker won't fit there.

also i really don't know how much is there needed to describe my problem.

[image: electrical panel]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photograph of the panel's labeling?  Should be a pretty big label possibly on the inside of the lid.  Also can you get a close-up of that label to the left of the main breaker that says "?? ??T USE ???SE STABS"?   I'd like to buy a vowel, Pat, is there an "O"?

Comment: Two thoughts: spot #1 appears to have a label that says “DO NOT USE THESE STABS”, possibly because of the 100A breaker on the other side. Second, it looks like you have 100A service (bottom left main breaker). Adding a 50A circuit for a hot tub might overload that.

Comment: does look like it says "do not use these stabs"

Comment: yes there is subpanel, i added more pictures

Answer (score 1):

Space marked 1 appears to have a label indicating you cannot use that space. That is common in panels that have stab limits, meaning the piece that opposing breakers clip onto can only handle the heat caused by up to a given limit. This limit would be found on the panel cover. It appears your bottom 100A and 20A may exceed stab limits too.

Space marked 2 is only a single pole, you would only get 120v from that space alone.

Your overall load is a concern, with a 100A in and a 100A out, but it seems like you aren't experiencing overload currrently, you may not if you add the hot tub. Likely the tub doesn't draw a full 50A.

Making space to accommodate a two-pole 50 can be made by substituting a breaker **similar** to a q25020c (upc 783643194984) in place of adjacent 20A breakers. I can't make a specific recommendation because you got tape gumming up critical information and you haven't provided.

But the biggest concern you got here is you appear to have breakers incompatible with the  *Listing* of the panel. You haven't provided specific information, but I have never seen an electrical panel that is NRTL (UL, CSA ,ETL or similar) approved for use with Siemens, Challenger, and Eaton circuit breakers. You should check the information on the panel cover and arrange to get breakers replaced that are compatible.

Also I can see a couple of places that it appears a ground wire and neutral are terminated in a single lug hole. I have seen panels that the listing and labeling allows multiple grounds, but never one that allows multiple wires with a neutral termination.

Comment: is it possible to move beakers to sub panel?

Comment: You could certainly move breakers to another panel if the breakers are compatible.

Comment: actually two breakers arent used on main panel, both below main 100amp top right, we just shut them off and couldn't find anything that was off